# NetSuite: Update Online Form Input Field

Tags: netsuite, online-forms

Does anyone know how to update the text size inside the input field? So far, this is what I have. If I update the input font-size, it also updates the button's size, which I don't want to do.

I also want to add the labels inside the input field but haven't had much luck. If anyone has succeeded doing so, please let me know.

```
<NLForm>
    <style>
    h1  {color: #464646;
        font-size: 20;
        }
    form {
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        }
    input {
        width: 400px;
        height: 40px;        
        font-size: 12px;
        }
    textarea {
        width: 530px;
        height:120px;
        }
    .btn {
        background-color: #d42027; 
        color:ffffff; 
        }


    </style>

    <HTML>
            <Head>
                <title> </title>
            </Head>

            <Body>

            <table width="50%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><h1>Name:</h1></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><nlfirstname></nlfirstname></td><td><nllastname></nllastname></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><h1>Email:</h1></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>    
                                            <td><nlemail></nlemail></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>    
                                            <td><nlcompanyname></nlcompanyname></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td> 
                            <td width="50%">
                                <table> 
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><h1>Comments:</h1></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><nlcomments></nlcomments><nlsubsidiary></nlsubsidiary></td>  
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table width="70%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="Submit" value="Send" class="btn"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            </Body>

        </HTML>
    </NLForm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to target only a specific type of `input` in your CSS you can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
/* This will target all the input controls */

input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
}

/* This will target only the text boxes */

input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* This will target only the submit box */

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #d42027; 
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```